# Make my browser treat current folder as root path

Tags: windows, browser

Say I have a bit of HTML that looks like:

```
<html> 
    <head> 
       <script src = "/app.js" type = "text/javascript"> 
    </head> 
</html>
```

And file structure like:

```
/dist 
  index.html
  app.js
```

If I upload the contents of `dist/` to an Amazon S3 bucket, this will be fine, because the root `/` refers to the bucket root.

However, on my local machine the `/` root refers to `C://` and the file will not be found.

Is there a way to trick my browser to into treating the folder that index.html is held in as root?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way I can think of is to put

```
<base href="C:/folder/">
```

near the top of each file. (This is supported by all major browsers)

Before uploading to the server, do a simple search and replace (replace with nothing)

Comment: That's not a bad solution I guess.

Comment: It would be easy to create a greasemonkey script to do this also, etc.

Comment: @user1068446 If this answer solved your problem, please mark this as solved. Thanks